# как в конструкторе switch сослаться на поле объекта

Tags: c#, классы, switch, case

```
internal class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string a = "форма гранит";
        switch (a)
        {
            case LibraryOfPrice.FG.NameWork:
                Console.WriteLine("yes");
                break;
        }
    }
}
public class LibraryOfPrice
{
    public string NameWork;
    public string Unit;
    public int Price;
    public Double PriceDouble;
    public LibraryOfPrice(string nameWork, string unit, int price = 0, double priceDouble = 0)
    {
        NameWork = nameWork;
        Unit = unit;
        Price = price;
        PriceDouble = priceDouble;
    }
    public static LibraryOfPrice FG = new LibraryOfPrice("форма гранит", "шт", 3000);
}
```

в Switch нужно сослаться на поле объекта, но компилятор пишет, что константа должна быть string, хотя она таковой и является.

Comment: Должна быть строкой это значит литералом, в Вашем случае используйте if-else

Comment: Ну либо поменять местами `a` и `LibraryOfPrice.FG.NameWork` в `switch` и `case` ))  Всё зависит от того, будут ли другие ещё какие-то `case` и какие именно.

Answer (score 3):

Вы неправильно работаете с [оператором switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-switch-statement). В скобках нужно указать переменную, а в case её возможные варианты, которые вы хотите обработать. А у вас наоборот - в скобках константа, а в case - переменная.

Comment: это я для примера написал. Там не важно что в скобках. Важно там только место которое после слова case. т.к в полной программе очень много полей объектов, которые надо сравнить в "кейсах", а переменная (в данном примере "а") всего одна